# SCP returns error when running in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sh

If I execute the same command in terminal it works, so if I execute it inside the shell script it returns "The file or directory does not exist". The command is the same inside the script and outside.

```
scp userNoRoot@1**.***.*.***:/remoteFile.tar.gz /destination
```

Full script

```
echo "---Start---"
scp userNoRoot@1**.***.*.***:/remotefile.tar.gz /destination
echo "---END---"
```

I call on a JAVA

```
String[] newExec= {"/script.sh"};

Process process1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(newExec);

BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process1.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

String result1 = br1.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

Comment: You are sending from the root of the filesystem `'/'`. Are you running as a different user in your script? Does the script user have the same file permissions that the person did running from the command line?

Comment: Yes, i send from de root of the filesystem. I execute the script or the command as the same user in both, i set 777 file permissions and it not works

Comment: The diference is that one is inside the scrip and not work and the other one is in the terminal and works

Comment: In the remote server. Please goto the directory where `remoteFile.tar.gz` is. And re-check the path with `pwd`

Comment: Use pwd command to check your 'Present Working Directory'

If they are different then you will not find the destination folder in one or the other it will be only available in one place.

If pwd returns same working directory then it is some other issue.

Comment: I use pwd and the directory is the same

Comment: Please post the whole script and the way how you run it.

Comment: I update the question

Comment: You script doesn't know where `scp` is. In Terminal, run `type scp` or `which scp` to get the full path, then put the full path into your script.

Comment: If i use the full path return the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must to add "-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa" after scp to identify the user and it works.